# Kotlin Gson parsing Json Object and Array

Tags: arrays, json, list, kotlin, gson

I am pretty new to Kotlin and Json and on my work I use GSON to parse the Json.
I need to parse the following Json file into a Class by using GSON.

```
 {
      "apiKey": "blablabla",
      "baseUrl": "blablabla",
      "requestData": [
        {
          "lng": "6.971",
          "lat": "50.942",
          "rad": "1.5",
          "type": [
                  "diesel",
                  "super"
          ]
        },
        {
          "lng": "6.442",
          "lat": "51.180",
          "rad": "1.5",
          "type": [
            "diesel",
            "super"
          ]
        },{
          "lng": "7.136",
          "lat": "50.991",
          "rad": "1.5",
          "type": [
            "diesel",
            "super"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Now I tried to make a data class like this:

```
data class ApiParameterData(
    var apiKey: String? = null,
    var baseUrl: String? = null,
    var requestData: String? = null) {

}
```

I also made another class to store the Json informations in it like this:

```
class Tankstelle: JsonDeserializer<ApiParameterData> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement?, typeOfT: Type?, context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): ApiParameterData {
        json as JsonObject

        val apiKey = json.get("apiKey").asString
        val baseUrl = json.get("baseUrl").asString
        val requestDataJson = json.get("requestData")
        val requestData = if (requestDataJson.isJsonObject) requestDataJson.asJsonObject.toString() else requestDataJson.toString()

        return ApiParameterData(apiKey, baseUrl, requestData)
    }
}
```

I tried to call it like that:

```
val gsonConfig = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(ApiParameterData::class.java, Tankstelle()).create()
val tanke = gsonConfig.fromJson(readJson, ApiParameterData::class.java)
println(tanke.requestData?.get(0))
```

But of course the output I get is "[" . I think because I get back a String or something and this is the first symbol of it?

I need to loop trough the requestData list and store it as a instance of a class and need to access each different value.
The thing is that I want to give the Json file different places and ranges it should look for gasstations. By reading the Json it should take all the pieces and create a link for each place I write in the requestData list. So in this case I would need 3 different links at the end. But this is another part I can do myself. I just don't know how to parse it so I can access and store every value in this Json.

Thank you already and have a great weekend!

If you need more informations just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to define two types that map to your `JSON` structure

```
class ApiParameterData(
        val apiKey: String,
        val baseUrl: String,
        val requestData: List<RequestObject>
)

class RequestObject(
        val lng: String,
        val lat: String,
        val rad: String,
        val type: List<String>
)
```

Now simply parse it as

```
val apiData = Gson().fromJson(readJson, ApiParameterData::class.java)     // No need to add TypeAdapter

// To get requestData
val requestData = apiData.requestData
requestData.forEach { 
  print("${it.lng}, ${it.lat}, ${it.rad}, ${it.type})
}
```